# SVG corrupted on save with content around artboard

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, artboard, save

I'm pretty new with Illustrator, All icons will be converted into icon web font for one of my projects.

When there are objects around the artboard (with or without **expand**) the file gets corrupted on converting.

**Error when converting**

> Strokes get ignored when generating fonts or CSH files.
>   You may convert them to fills and reimport your SVG(s).

I saw there was an option for Use Artboards on save and tried without luck.

I temporary delete everything around the artboard when saving and ctrl+z, but that's not a good solution for me.

There must be a way to have objects around the artboard and still be able to save it successfully.

[image: My artboard]
[image: My save settings]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of Save as... use the **Asset Export Window**

- Select the illustration and drag it to the window holding
  <kbd>Alt</kbd>
- Check the SVG export settings if necessary launching the **Export for Screen Dialog** icon at the bottom
- Click the **Export** button

[image: Asset Export Window]

Comment: I will definitely check this out

Comment: To turn off the sub-folder creation hit Alt + Ctrl + E on windows and Cmd + Opt + E on mac